# How to flash fill a formula in Excel using a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm self taught in VBA and wasn't able to decipher the other answers to this question. I have a formula in J6 that I want to fill down to the end of the data.

I have the following code:

```
Range("j6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],R5C14:R6C15,2,FALSE),2)"
Range("J6").Select
Range("J6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J6:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlDown).Row)
```

I thought this would count the rows in column I with data and then fill down that far but it flash fills all the way down.

```
Range("j6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],R5C14:R6C15,2,FALSE),2)"
Range("J6").Select
Range("J6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J6:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlDown).Row)
```

I would like the formula to flash fill to the end of the data set.

Comment: you want `xlUp` not `xlDown`

Comment: `Range("J6:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],R5C14:R6C15,2,FALSE),2)"`  Replaces all four lines

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner's one line fix in the comment above works. The code I'm posting below is not a one line solution, rather it separates the 'applying of the formula' from the defining / finding of the bottom row of column J.

```
Sub Formuala()

Dim LastRow As Long

'code below finds that last cell in Column J so the formula can be applied from J6 down
'to this "LastRow" which can be different each time the macro is run

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Code below place the formula on the sheet for the J6 to J"LastRow" range
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J6:J" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],R5C14:R6C15,2,FALSE),2"

End Sub
```

Be sure to change `Sheet1` in my code to whatever your worksheet is named.

Good luck and welcome to the site!